# Am I able to use open source code for my games?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I believe Ray Wenderlich tutorials are open source ,so can I use the code for my game? I still need to modify it in order to work with my game ,but i don't want to get in any legal trouble. Im pretty sure i am able to, but just wanted to make sure. Any suggestions.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a legal question site. If you have questions about licensing issues, contact the author or publisher of the source code, or an attorney in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 4):

Read the FAQ: http://www.raywenderlich.com/faq

> **What is the License for the Tutorial Source Code?**
>
> The license for the source code in the free tutorials is the MIT
>   license, except when specified otherwise. No attribution is required
>   (but is of course appreciated!)
>
> Full text below:
>
> Copyright (c) 2010, 2011 Ray Wenderlich
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software to deal in the Software without restriction,
>   including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge,
>   publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software,
>   and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
>   subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

But here isn't the place where you should ask something like that...